# apply ng-show and ng-hide on condition based for dynimcally created elements angular js ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

apply required filed for some filed in my form but my form is created using the custom directive, So Html is created Dynamically. I am using ng-repeat, i need to show some fields are required when user enter the submit button, but it is showing all fields is required.

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type=[item.name]>
 </div>


<p ng-show="ErrorMsg">Error Message </p>
```

when i am checking the controller logic

```
Controller.js

$scope.ErrorMsg = false;

if(item.value == null){
   $scope.ErrorMsg = true;
```

}

But it is showing all fields for error msg. Please suggest me how to approach

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to include more of your code. Your title is about conditional css (see `ng-class`) but your question seems to be about an error message??

Answer (score 0):

I create a simple plunkr about angularjs dynamic form validation, please refer here:http://plnkr.co/edit/7OJHKsJPoHNqeeStBtnh.

```js
// Code goes here
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('DemoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  function setTouched(form) {
    angular.forEach(form, function (value, key) {
      if (!/^\$/.test(key)) {
        form[key].$setTouched();
      }
    });
  }
    
  var config = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var item = {};
    item.name = 'input' + i;
    item.required = (i%2 === 0) ? true : false;
    config[i] = item;
  }
  $scope.config = config;
  $scope.save = function() {
    if ($scope.testForm.$invalid) {
      setTouched($scope.testForm);
    }
  }
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.3.6" data-semver="1.3.6" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-messages@*" data-semver="1.3.16" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DemoController">
    <form name="testForm" ng-submit="save()" novalidate>
      <div ng-repeat="item in config">
        <input type="text" name="{{item.name}}" ng-model="item.value"
        ng-required="item.required" />
      <div ng-messages="testForm[item.name].$error"
      ng-if="testForm[item.name].$invalid && testForm[item.name].$touched">
      <div ng-message="required">this is required</div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">save</button>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope this can help :)